# How to reference index attributes in groupby chain statement without the DataFrame name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, chaining

Is there a way to write `groupby` by index.attributes in chain after DataFrame creation like this?

```
pd.read_excel('some_excel.xlsx').groupby(index.time)['some_var'].sum()
```

I'm able to do it in two lines with referencing DataFrame by name like this:

```
a = pd.read_excel('some_excel.xlsx')
b = a.groupby(a.index.time)['some_var'].sum()
```

or in one line with dummy column creation like this:

```
pd\
 .read_excel('some_excel.xlsx')\
 .assign(time = lambda x: x.index.time)\
 .groupby('time')\
 ['some_var'].sum()
```

but i wonder if there is a one-line way without additional assignments?

Thank you for answer or link to it.

P.S. Originally index is a datetime (e.g. '2018-05-01 13:15:00') column, and there is no column with 'time' name.

Comment: In [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), you can use level as paramater to group on an index, so maybe try `groupby(level='time')` in your first line of code

Comment: @Ben.T originally index is a datetime column, and there is no column with 'time' name. Sorry for not clarifying this moment. So to do like you suggest, I must firstly create index level with such name, which will be equal to third variant.

Comment: Just do `groupby(level=0)` to group by the first level, name doesn't matter.

Comment: @KenSyme but i need to group not by index itself, but by index.attribute. In my case attribute is time, but it can by index.date or index.month or whatever.

Comment: Ah OK, I had not realised that from your question. I do not believe there is a way to do that, so I could probably go for the 2 line approach. Note if you are doing a multiline thing like your last snippet, you can wrap the whole thing in parenthesis and have a newline after each `.` without having to use the \, it is a lot cleaner!

Comment: @KenSyme thx for the parenthesis hint! By the way, it is possible - check the assepted answer from Ben.T. I was close with 'lambda' function but not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so actually, if 'time' is an attribute of the index, you can use a `lambda` in the `groupby` such as:

```
pd.read_excel('some_excel.xlsx').groupby(lambda x: x.time)['some_var'].sum()
```

and it should work.